# unable to redirect output of executable made by Matlab Compiler

Tags: matlab, redirect, command-prompt

I made an executable by Matlab Coder of this simple code :

```
function hello (s_a,d_b,d_c)
    fprintf('%s\n',s_a);
    fprintf('%d\n',d_b/d_c);
    fprintf('%d\n',d_b*d_c);
end
```

When I run this executable on the window command prompt, I can see the result.

When I use the redirection of the StandardOuptut and the redirection of the StandardError, my file is created but it is empty.

I tried the redirection on a simple command and it works for me.

So, i think that the problem comes to my executable. 
Do you know how to redirect the output of an executable that was made by Matlab ?